# Is there a way to combine if statment with filter function?

Tags: r, if-statement

I need to filter out some rows if a condition is true.

Tried this:

```
if(DiffTask$TaskCue == "square1"){DiffTasks<-subset(data,-subject==10)}
```

Warning message:

> In if (DiffTask$TaskCue == "square1") { :   the condition has length >
>   1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you. Also if you google your warning message there are lot of posts which help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect any number of logical conditions, e.g.

```
DiffTask <- data.frame(TaskCue = rep(c("square1", "square2"), 5),
                       subject = rep(10:6, 2))

subset(DiffTask, !(TaskCue == "square1" & subject == 10))
```